# Monitoring TCP traffic that contains specific strings in C#

Tags: c#, tcp, monitor, network-traffic

Recently one of my machines was infected with malware using IRC to communicate back to it's command and control center.

This just sparked interest within me to see if there was a program I could create in C# that is capable of monitoring traffic over TCP that contains strings such as PONG / NICK / USER (strings the irc rfc needs to communicate), and then can tell me the process that that traffic is coming from.

It would be an interesting learning experience for me, and it's something that I want to attempt.

I've done some research and I found something that did make use of WinPcap but i think I'd like to avoid a solution using pcap if possible, can anyone send any suggestions my way?

I know I may be able to view connections between my computer and other hosts using **System.Net.NetworkInformation.TcpConnectionInformation** and possibly **IPGlobalProperties** but I'm not sure if there is anyway I can view the information in realtime, or easily trace it back to a process on my PC.

Thank you.

Comment: why not use winpcap? windump and ethereal both use it, it's quite mature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be hard. The API you need is native, [Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463267.aspx). According to Microsoft, this is not accessible from C#, you would have to wrap it in C++/CLI first.

See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfp/thread/e2308de1-e892-4a07-9bc8-7278d1f5b104) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfp/thread/a65bf197-937b-401e-b15f-0e1c3decdb14) for discussion.  The second thread has some 'could be useful' stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Steve, but are there any other possible solutions that can work on Windows XP too? It seems that WFP is only available in Server 2008 on up.

Comment: Would monitoring raw sockets always be an option as well?

Comment: In Windows XP you are limited to kernel-mode filtering afaik. Not going to play well with managed code. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546594(v=VS.85).aspx